The x field is required error in EF Core requests
If got a controller endpoint expecting a DTO with just a list of Ids to fetch this specific list of IDs. When sending the following request to the endpoint, it returns an error

the idList field is required

I tried sending it multiple ways.
This is the controller method in question:
[HttpGet("listById")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ListById([FromBody] IdListDto idList) =>
       await Handle(Service.FindByList(idList));

The DTO:
public record IdListDto : IIdListDto
{
    public ulong[]? Ids { get; set; }
}

Postman request and result:
Postman-Request and Result
I tried changing the request in different ways, like wrapping the "Ids" parameter in an idList JSON object, but the result is the same. I don't actually need the DTO and tried using just a simple array, but it didn't recognize that either.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

According to the HTTP/1.1 specification, GET requests should not have a message body. Use HttpPost instead.

I'm sorry but I didn't reproduce your issue in my side. Could you please share a  minimal sample? https://i.sstatic.net/V077leMt.png

Hey there, I gave up trying and used FormData instead, it works now as I wanted it to. Sorry for the inconvenience!

I changed "FromBody" to "FromForm" and now it works. I know this is probably the wrong way to handle this, but I need to move on.
I'll look into it again at a later stage and edit my question with an qualified explanation of what went wrong.

The reason of the issue is using [FromBody] in a GET request. You cannot use [FromBody] in a "GET" request. Simply because GET requests have no body.
What you can do is to use [FromQuery] instead. Your code should look like the one below
[HttpGet(Name = "listById")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ListById([FromQuery] ulong[]? idList) =>
    await Handle(Service.FindByList(idList));

Moreover, you must call the GET action above like the following URL with query parameters
yourdomain.com/..../listById?idList=1&idList=2&idList=3
Update:
If you are worried about the limit of the query parameter length on that your webserver can accept, you can change this limit like this for IIS:
<system.webServer>
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="1024" maxUrl="2048">
           <headerLimits>
              <add header="Content-type" sizeLimit="100" />
           </headerLimits>
        </requestLimits>
     </requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>


Thanks for the explanation! That helps a lot! But I dont like to use [FromQuery], since in this case the query could contain 100 IDs. I resorted to [FromForm] as this does strangely work with GET-Requests. Else I would have changed it to a post request, although not being very clean.

I understand. I have updated my answer to address the problem of query string limit length
